# POPsql is stuck at startup, what can i do?

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

i have been using POPsql for over a week for learning sql but today it refuses to work. It has been stuck on the initial loading screen for more than half an hour. I have tried restarting the laptop, clearing the ram and closing any useless apps running in the background, but nothing changed. I even tried running it as administrator, still nothing.
What else can I do?

Comment: Not sure what OS you are using but checking the OS logs would be a good next step.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and I tried reinstall the program with no success.
the solution that worked for me is uninstalling and deleting this folder C:\Users\Bodas\AppData\Roaming\PopSQL ,
it is kind of a refresh start when you install it again.

Comment: This is not good solution, What if you face the same challenge after reinstallation

Answer (score 0):

On the PopSql window, go to help > go to Troubleshooting > Clear cache and restart.

Hope it helps! Good luck!